# Distinct React forms are sharing state, how to separate them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

My situation is that, depending on a value of a prop to my form (specifically `step`) I need to render distinct forms. This is fine; it loads the text of the form programmatically as desired, and populates the form. However, when that value of `step` changes, the text and input type and so on all change, but the *user specified inputs* are shared.

Note that `step` is managed by redux state and altered by various actions throughout the application. Altering state does cause the component to redraw correctly.

That is, if the user inputs `foo` on the third box and hits "next", the form redraws with new text, formatting, etc., but `foo` is still put in the third box of the new form. This is not what I want; keeping state between redraws is nice (but not required), while sharing states between distinct forms is definitely not what I want.

How can I explain to the browser that these are different forms?

Here is a sample of broken code (the real code is more complex but this demonstrates the problem). Note that `id` has no functional purpose, except that I thought it might disambiguate the forms (it had no effect).:

```
const CenterFormInput = ({
  formElement: { inputType, elementName, help, label },
  helpTextSetter
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{label}</p>
      <p>
        <input name={elementName} type="text" />
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};

const FormContentComponent = ({ formElements, helpTextSetter, id }) => (
  <form id={id}>
    {formElements.map((elt, i) => (
      <CenterFormInput
        formElement={elt}
        helpTextSetter={helpTextSetter}
        key={i}
      />
    ))}
  </form>
);

const FormContent = ({ step, helpTextSetter }) => {
  // index pages from zero, but steps start at one

  step -= 1;

  if (step >= 0 && step < contentPages.length) {
    const { formElements, id } = contentPages[step];
    return (
      <FormContentComponent
        formElements={formElements}
        helpTextSetter={helpTextSetter}
        formId={id}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return <div>{`No form found for step ${step}`}</div>;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you add in which component is your "next" button present?

Comment: @NamanKheterpal done; it's populated through the redux state

Answer (score 1):

This is the general case in which props of component are getting changed and so re-rendering of component happens with new props.

But as it seems you are not taking `value` of the `input` box from the props, only attributes of the `input` box will be changed according to the new props passed to `CenterFormInput`

Try passing `value` of the field also in the props (may be empty or null by default)

```
const CenterFormInput = ({
  formElement: { inputType, value = null, elementName, help, label },
  helpTextSetter
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{label}</p>
      <p>
        <input name={elementName} value={value} type="text" />
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and update the value on `onChange` event of the input box. This will reset the value of `input` box on re-rendering or set it to the value passed.

Or you can also make the Statefull component and maintain the value in state and reset it on `componentWillRecieveProps` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` depending on version of react you are using.

Feel free to add comment in case of further details.